# Ударение в слове "деньгами"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно говорить: "д***е***ньгами" или "деньг***а***ми"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По современным нормам русского языка правильно говорить "деньг**а**ми". Форма "д**е**ньгами" тоже допустима, но является устаревшей.

Answer (score 2):

Словари уже запрещают форму "дЕньгами", считая, что она уместна только в пословице "не в дЕньгах счастье". К сожалению, эта рекомендация соблюдается  далеко не всегда и далеко не всеми. Интересно, что в поэзии применяются обе формы,например: "Кто без страха и упрека - тот всегда не при деньгАх" и "Я и сам бы взял кило, да плохо с дЕньгами". В последнем варианте такая форма используется, скорее, в качестве речевой характеристики персонажа.

Comment: Почему "к сожалению"? Люди, которые всю жизнь говорили правильно "дЕньгами", должны переучиваться? Я думаю, старшая норма уходит постепенно, с уходом её носителей. Да и словари далеко не все запрещают. В большинстве словарей указываются оба варианта.

Comment: Количество вариантов следует неуклонно сокращать, так как они способствуют разобщенности нации. Давайте возьмем пример с Франции: там ударение неподвижное и одноместное, и поэтому все любят друг друга. А у нас те, кто говорит "тврОг", с неудовольствием смотрит на тех, кто говорит "твОрог".

Answer (score 1):

Конечно правильно говорить дЕньгами, но все говорят деньгАми. Так же, как слово КАТАЛОГ. Правильно каталОг, а почему-то многие говорят катАлог.
Я иногда спрашиваю сказавшего - А кАталог в магАзине КУПЛЯЛ?

Answer (score 1):

Пусть деньгА. Но множественное число все же дЕньги. Не деньгИ!

Comment: Ударение в слове “деньгами” на кону.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

ударение в слове деньгАми на А, так как слово деньгА, ударение на А!!!!! говорить правильно во все времена МОДНО!

Comment: Очень странная логика.